# java.util.Calendar not setting Month correctly

Tags: java, date, calendar

The issue is pretty simple. What I want is to create a Calendar and set it with this attributes:
Day: 17
Month: 10 (october)
Year: 1989

But the calendar is not setting the MONTH properly.

This is the code:

```
Calendar fecha = new GregorianCalendar();
fecha.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 17);
fecha.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.OCTOBER);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(fecha.getTime()));
```

And what I'm getting:
17/01/2013     ------------>The month is not October

What's wrong with this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to set the month and the year, then when you set the day, use [`DAY_OF_MONTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH) instead of `DAY_OF_YEAR`.

Answer (score 3):

```
fecha.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 17);
```

belongs to JANUARY

You need to set `Calendar.DATE`

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
Calendar fecha = new GregorianCalendar();
fecha.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 17);
fecha.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.OCTOBER);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(fecha.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use DAY_OF_MONTH instead of DAY_OF_YEAR

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It's work Fine, also Display Month in Words.

```
  `Calendar fecha = new GregorianCalendar();
    fecha.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 17);
    fecha.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.OCTOBER);
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMMM/yyyy").format(fecha.getTime()));`
```